# If there are common attributes in the table in the FROM clause of inner and outer query?

Tags: sql, database

Schema for table A:  A(**x**,y,z)
Schema for table B:  B(**u**,x,v)

[Primary keys mentioned in bold]

For the SQL query as mentioned:-

```
SELECT x
FROM   A
WHERE x in ( SELECT x 
           FROM B
           WHERE x<10)
```

How does the inner query resolve that this x mentioned is from the table B and not the table A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is resolved from the innermost query out.  It is always better to qualify column names, so write this query as:

```
SELECT A.x
FROM A
WHERE A.x IN (SELECT B.x 
              FROM B
              WHERE B.x < 10
             );
```

This has the advantage that if `B.x` does not exist, you will get an error.  Otherwise, the `IN (SELECT x . . .` will refer to `A.x` (but only when `B.x` does not exist).

Comment: If column names are not qualified they will be resolved by the innermost query?